# no such column: user.is_admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a model with SQLAlchemy (with Flask), but I cannot able to fix this problem

**this is the error that shows while i try to run the app**

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.is_admin
> [SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.image_file AS user_image_file, user.password AS user_password, user.is_admin AS user_is_admin
> FROM user
> WHERE user.id = ?]
> [parameters: (1,)]

**model.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from flaskblog import db, login_manager, app
from flask_login import UserMixin



@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):  
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
     email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
     image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
     password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
     posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
     is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
     

     def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
         s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
         return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

     @staticmethod
     def verify_reset_token(token):
         s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
         try:
             user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
         except:
             return None
         return User.query.get(user_id)

     def __repr__(self):
         return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"



class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
    # Define the UserRoles data model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentions that your SQLite table `user` does not contain a column with the name `is_admin`, you should check your table `user` in the database file, you have incorrect spelling or forget to add that column.